# Renovar dados na mesma activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá!
Gostaria de saber como ir alternando valores sempre numa mesma activity.
Não sei se é bem assim que se diz, mas vou explicar dando como exemplo
um aplicativo de tabuada que tenho aqui e é o que realmente pretendo fazer.
Nesse aplicativo ele mostra a conta, você responde, certo ou errado as
contas vão se alternando.
Como faço para que sempre numa mesma tela as contas irem se alternando?
obrigado

Comment: Olá. Seja bem-vindo(a) ao StackOverflow em Português. Sua pergunta está um tanto vazia. Coloque aí o código da sua Activity.

Comment: De qualquer modo, os métodos `setText` dos componentes provavelmente textuais são o que você provavelmente está procurando.